Calculate standard deviation for difference of two populations
I have two populations, let's say $P_1$ and $P_2$, and they have their own standard deviations, like $STD_1$ and $STD_2$. From this populations I need to calculate which one is better. I do that by comparing their averages, but how can I apply both $STD_1$ and $STD_2$ to see the standard deviation of the result?
For example, I have $P_1 = \{4, 5, 6, 4\}$ and $P_2 = \{7, 8, 9, 7\}$, average (mean) of $P_1$ is $M_1 = \frac{4 + 5 + 6 + 4}{4} = 4,75$ and for $P_2$ I have $M_2 = \frac{7 + 8 + 9 + 7}{4} = 7,74$. I can see that $P_2$ is "better", but they both have some standard deviations $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = 0,83$, here they are equal, but this is not the requirement.
And my question is that I know that both populations have some standard deviations, but how can I combine them to see the actual deviation of these two populations?

What do you mean by "better"? Also, this question might be more appropriate for Cross Validated.

@RKLS, I added an example
